# ViewModel emiting multiple times instead of just once

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mvvm, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to just emit just once in this fragment, it emits the first time I enter this fragment, but if I navigate to the next fragment and come back, it will emit again and I dont want that because it will refetch my data, instead I want to avoid refetching if I come back to this fragment.

### Fragment

```
 private val viewModel by viewModels<LandingViewModel> {
        VMLandingFactory(
            LandingRepoImpl(
                LandingDataSource()
            )
        )
    }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("LOCATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val nombre = sharedPref.getString("name", null)
        location = name!!
    }

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupRecyclerView()
        fetchShops(location)
    }

 private fun fetchShops(localidad: String) {

        viewModel.setLocation(location.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).trim())
        viewModel.fetchShopList
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

                when (it) {

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        showProgress()
                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        hideProgress()
                        myAdapter.setItems(it.data)
                    }
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        hideProgress()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "There was an error loading the shops.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            })

    }
```

### Viewmodel

```
 private val locationQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setLocation(location: String) {
        locationQuery.value = location
    }

    val fetchShopList = locationQuery.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { location ->
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.getShopList(location))
            }catch (e:Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
        }
```

Here, location is not changing when I go to the next fragment and come back. Any ideas how to fix this ? I'm using navigation components.

Comment: If you doing bottom navigation, stay on the fragment and tap twice on same fragment with bottom nav and it emits the value again and again then its not a viewModel  observer problem but your fragments recreates, i kinda agree with @Joozd's answer below... and why you are reading different situations in switchMap block? do that in repository and keep the switchMap little clean.

Answer (score 1):

That is how `LiveData` works, it will always give you the latest information it has when resuming. I would suggest using kotlin's `Flow` as this does what you want where after you are done emitting you dont get anymore updates

Comment: But I dont need a reactive fetching of the data, I need to fetch it just once, this has to be something with the fragment state

Comment: no its not, live data will always give you what it has so you have content to show while you load new data. Right from the documentation `If a lifecycle becomes inactive, it receives the latest data upon becoming active again. For example, an activity that was in the background receives the latest data right after it returns to the foreground.`

Comment: With `Flow` you emit once and then its done. Flow is similar to live data where you subscribe to it but done get the callback upon the activity/fragment becoming active again

Comment: but this is not about active fragment in background is about navigating to another fragment (destroying current fragment) and coming back, the viewmodel will also be dettached and destroyed because of the lifecycleowner, and then created again and refetch (emit again) with flow will be the same

Comment: If everything is destroyed like you say then of course you are going to still get data since onViewCreated will be called again which calls `fetchShops(location)` not sure what you expect here, what will show if you dont want to re-fetch?

Comment: when I press onBackButton from fragment B , I dont want Fragment A to refetch, thats what I asked

Comment: if the fragment is being created like it did not exist (which I am skeptical about if its actually getting fully destroyed like you say since that breaks the fragment lifecycle) its has no idea if you are going to or back to it, its going to always fetch you will just show an empty screen if it didnt. You wll need to keep a boolean or something in your activity and pass it to the fragment again

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) it should emit only once

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question yesterday, tried to research I answer without success on why the *distinctUntilChanged()* wasn't working for you - to be honest I never worked with that "extenstion" that was added a while ago.

In any case, a quickfix would be to add an *alreadyLoaded* variable, like this:

```
 private val locationQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()

 private var alreadyLoaded = false

    fun setLocation(location: String) {
    if (!alreadyLoaded) {
        alreadyLoaded = true
        locationQuery.value = location
     }

    }

    val fetchShopList = locationQuery.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { location ->
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.getShopList(location))
            }catch (e:Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewmodel doesn't emit more than once. Your activity get's recreated, so you observe more than once. (it will also happen when you rotate screen, etcetera)

[This](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) gentleman has a really nice and clear blog about this very situation